# Failed to install gem rest-client

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, rest-client, rhel7

I am trying to install gem res-client in my redhat linux server.Installed whatever dependencies i found but still not working for me.

> Ruby Version:
>
> ruby 2.3.6p384 (2017-12-14 revision 61254) [x86_64-linux]
>
> [root@feeds ]# gem install rest-client
>
> Building native extensions. This could take a while...
>
> ERROR:  Error installing rest-client:
>
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> current directory: /opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/local/share/gems/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.6/ext/unf_ext
>
> /opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/bin/ruby -I /opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby -r ./siteconf20190429-62674-e4of20.rb extconf.rb
>
> checking for main() in -lstdc++... no
>   creating Makefile
>
> current directory: /opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/local/share/gems/gems/unf_ext-
>   0.0.7.6/ext/unf_ext
>
> make "DESTDIR=" clean
>
> rm -f
>
> rm -f unf_ext.so  *.o  *.bak mkmf.log .*.time
>
> current directory: /opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/local/share/gems/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.6/ext/unf_ext
>
> make "DESTDIR="
>   g++ -I. -I/opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/include -I/opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/include -I.   -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -mtune=generic -m64 -o unf.o -c unf.cc
>
> make: g++: Command not found
>
> make: *** [unf.o] Error 127
>
> make failed, exit code 2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/local/share/gems/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.6 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/local/lib64/gems/ruby/unf_ext-0.0.7.6/gem_make.out

Can anyone please suggest.

Thanks
Sina

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the gcc-c++ compiler. Install it with:

```
yum install gcc-c++
```

Answer (score 0):

`build-essential g++` are the missing ones. So try installing:

```
yum install build-essential g++
```

then install the required gem:

```
gem install rest-client
```

hope it helps....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks .

I reinstall ruby and dependencies then it worked.

Regards,

Sina